# Using EF with stored procedure and getting error as New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern, dbcontext, unit-of-work

In Entity framework, I have implemented generic repository and unit of work pattern.

Below is related stuff from unit of work:

```
    public IRepository<TEntity, TKey> GetRepository<TEntity, TKey>() where TEntity : class
    {
        if (_repositories == null)
        {
            _repositories = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        }

        string key = String.Format("{0}|{1}", typeof(TEntity).Name, typeof(TKey).Name);

        if (_repositories.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return (IRepository<TEntity, TKey>)_repositories[key];
        }

        Type repositoryType = typeof(Repository<TEntity, TKey>);
        _repositories.Add(key, Activator.CreateInstance(repositoryType, _dataContext));

        return (IRepository<TEntity, TKey>)_repositories[key];
    }
```

From Manager layer, entity framework is call as below:

```
     IRepository<tablenameEntity int> _tableEntityRepository =  _unitOfWork.GetRepository<tablenameEntity, int>();
```

Error is as follow:

`An error occurred while starting a transaction on the provider connection. See the inner exception for details.`

`{"New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session."}.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I just did as below,

> > remove stored procedure and function from model browser and added procedure and function again.
> >
> > run custom tool on edmx file.

It just work out.

I am not sure, what was the issue. did that before also, but it was not work.. now, it works and not produce after that.

Thanks

Comment: You can "accept" your own answer by selecting the "tick". This removes it from the queue of unanswered questions.